# Add message to group using Facebook Graph API returns all posts (JSON format)

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, facebook-group

I am trying to post to a group that i own on Facebook. When i paste the address in browser to add a message, it just returns a JSON with the last posts (not a * success* as expected), and doesn't post the message.

The url is `https://graph.facebook.com/MyGroupName/feed?message=Test&access_token=APP|ACCESSTOKEN`

If i remove the access token, it replies `"An access token is required to request this resource."`, so it doesn't seem like an access problem. I am using the method described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing

**EDIT**: If i change method to POST, i receive 403 forbidden.

So my question is, why isn't my message posted?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, why isn't my message posted?

Because your browser makes a GET request for anything you type into the address bar - and you want to make a POST request.

You can add a parameter `method=POST`, then the API will treat it as if it was an actual POST request.

If you want to test(?) more stuff like this, I would recommend using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) though. That has an easy interface to simulate requests like this.

Comment: The `message=`parameter is for message. If i change the method to POST i get **403 Forbidden**. I edited my original message.

Comment: @Tiago sorry, typo - it is of course `method=POST`, not message.

Comment: You need `publish_actions` and `user_managed_groups` permission from the user, do you have those?